# Simple Form and routing errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, simple-form-for

View/Form

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="ibox-content">
                <div class="row">
                        <%= simple_form_for supplier_fuel_prices_path(@supplier,@fuel_price), method: :post do |f| %>
                          <%= f.input :regular, label: "Regular" %>
                          <%= f.input :medium, label: "Medium"%>
                          <%= f.input :premium, label: "Premium" %>
                          <%= f.input :diesel, label: "Diesel" %>
                        <%= f.button :submit, "Update"%>
                        <%end%>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

controller

```
class Supplier::FuelPricesController < Supplier::ApplicationController
  before_action :set_supplier

  def index
  end

  def new
    @fuel_price = @supplier.fuel_prices.build
  end

  def create
    @fuel_price = @supplier.fuel_price.build(fuel_price_params)
    if @fuel_price.save
      flash[:notice] = "You have successfully Added new Fuel Price."
      redirect_to supplier_fuel_prices_path
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Something went wrong. Please try again."
      render "new"
    end
  end

  private

  def fuel_price_params
    params.require(:fuel_price).permit(:regular, :medium, :premium, :diesel)
  end

  def set_supplier
    @supplier = User.find_by(params[:supplier_id])
  end
end
```

Models

User model has   has_many :fuel_prices, foreign_key: :supplier_id

Fuel Price Model has belongs_to "supplier", class_name: "User"

Error i am getting when submitting the form is

**No route matches [POST] "/supplier/fuel_prices/new"**

My routes looks like this

```
 namespace :supplier do
    root to: 'dashboard#index', as: 'dashboard'
    resources :retailers
    resources :fuel_prices

  end
```

Routes

supplier_fuel_prices_path   GET /supplier/fuel_prices(.:format) 
POST    /supplier/fuel_prices(.:format) supplier/fuel_prices#create

new_supplier_fuel_price_path    GET /supplier/fuel_prices/new(.:format) supplier/fuel_prices#new

edit_supplier_fuel_price_path   GET /supplier/fuel_prices/:id/edit(.:format)    supplier/fuel_prices#edit
supplier_fuel_price_path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just trying to `post` to the wrong path. A url ending in new is typically going to be a `get` request. Run `rake routes` and make sure you're posting to the correct `post` route and update your form.

Comment: I did this <%= simple_form_for([@supplier, @supplier.fuel_prices.build]) do |f| %> then  i am getting new error saying   ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `user_fuel_prices_path' for #<#<Class:0x0055eeaefe1760>:0x0055eeaf4b42b0>

Comment: I have supplier_fuel_prices_path , but how do i make it work with supllier rather than user. I have user model and types.